# What sets template page/html/head.phtml

Tags: layout, template, ee-1.13

This is the general layout for all pages. In page.xml, there is this code

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
  <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/1column.phtml">
      <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
```

Now in page/1column.phtml, there is this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
```

So I'm pretty sure `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>` starts including the contents of `head` block in page.xml, e.g. `css/styles.css`. Somehow in the view source, there is all the content in head.phtml between `<head>` and `css/styles.css`, but I have no idea what is putting it there. I don't see anything setting head.phtml in this layout file or local.xml. Does anyone know where this template is included in code? I think finding this will help me uncover a bug I'm experiencing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the template file is not set through xml, rather it is defined in block.
at location

```
app/code/core/mage/page/html/head.php
```

you will see this code

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('page/html/head.phtml');
    $this->setData('is_enterprise', Mage::getEdition() == Mage::EDITION_ENTERPRISE);
}
```

this piece of code is responsible for setting head.phtml template

Comment: Ah yeah, and that's set by `<block type="page/html_head"`. Thank you.